# Wordpress jQuery Click not working. Please help :)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

Some jQuery works and some don't. In this case the click function is not working.

This code works:-

```
  $j=jQuery.noConflict();

   // Use jQuery via $j(...)
  $j(document).ready(function(){
    alert('test');
   });
```

However this doesn't. This is what I've done:- Its from this codepen :-
http://codepen.io/domierosina/pen/qdYRYM

Demo1.js :-

```
var $j=jQuery.noConflict();

 // Use jQuery via $j(...)
  $j(document).ready(function(){
  $j('#overlay-menu').click(function() {
  $j('.overlay').addClass('overlay-open');
    $j('.menuButton').hide();
  });
  $j('.overlay-close').click(function() {
     $j('.overlay').removeClass('overlay-open');
    $j('.menuButton').show();
  });
  });
```

In functions.php (child theme)

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
  function add_my_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
    'demo1', 
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/demo1.js', 
    array('jquery') 
  );
  }
```

In Html :-

```
  <div id="container">
    <button id="overlay-menu" class="menuButton" type="button">Menu</button>
   </div>

   <div class="overlay overlay-data">
     <button type="button" class="overlay-close">Close</button>
      <nav>
     <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
     </ul>
    </nav>
     </div>
```

Upon clicking Menu button, nothing happens.

Checking Inspect element in Firefox, the demo1.js is loaded without any issues in

Comment: can you try $j('.menuButton').click(function() ... instead?  I don't know if WordPress uses any kind of Master Page, but the IDs sometimes get thrown off.  I typically use classes as a selector to make that easier

Comment: Tried it, no luck. The class overlay-open doesn't get appended to overlay

Answer (score 0):

Looks line the menu button works fine!

```js
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

// Use jQuery via $j(...)
$j(document).ready(function() {
  $j('#overlay-menu').click(function() {
    $j('.overlay').addClass('overlay-open');
    $j('.menuButton').hide();
  });
  $j('.overlay-close').click(function() {
    $j('.overlay').removeClass('overlay-open');
    $j('.menuButton').show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <button id="overlay-menu" class="menuButton" type="button">Menu</button>
</div>

<div class="overlay overlay-data">
  <button type="button" class="overlay-close">Close</button>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: It just doesnt work in my Wordpress... I have no idea why

Comment: check what html is being rendered - does it include demo.js

Comment: Yep it does.. from the JS folder Child theme where the file is located.

Comment: Are you sure jqueryv is being installed then? Of you JavaScript is good, which it seems to be, then you need to make die it is loaded and run